# x86 Assembly Add operands with different sizes

Tags: assembly, x86

I like to add a byte from a memory location to a 32bit register,
is this possible in x86 assembly?
`add edx, byte [ebx]` causes `error: mismatch in operand sizes`

Comment: You'll need to zero or sign-extend the small operand.

Comment: With `movzx eax, byte [ebx]
 add edx, eax` it is working. Thank you!

Comment: @kaetzacoatl it depends. Check my answer for details

Comment: I'm working with unsigned integers, so movzx works fine for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that the operands are of the same size.

This involves a problem with the sign though. If you are working with *signed* integers you should use [movsx](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_206.html), or use [movzx](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_209.html) if you are working with *unsigned* integers.

```
movsx/movzx eax, byte ptr [ebx]
add edx, eax
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if first operand is register or memory and second operand is immediate.

```
Opcode   |Instruction     | Description
83 /0 ib |ADD r/m32, imm8 | Add sign-extended imm8 to r/m32.
```

[from here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf

Comment: That imm8 is just a compact encoding for a 32-bit value in the range -128 .. +127.  The operand-size for that `add` instruction is still 32-bit, the sign-extension happens as part of decoding it.  And the assembler will do it for you if you write `add ecx, 123`, you don't need `add ecx, strict byte 123`.